# Inheritance with static values

Tags: java, inheritance, static, final, extends

I have a parent class called `Product` and a child called `Food`. Every `Product` has a delivery time. For instance for `Food` it is one day (which I define as an `int` of one).

I made my `Product` class like this:

```
public abstract class Product {    
    private int id;
    private String description;
    private double price;

    public Product(int id, String description, double price) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
    }.... and so on
```

My `Food` class looks like this:

```
public class Food extends Product{

    private Date expirationDate;
    private static final int DELIVERY = 1;

    public Food(int id, String description, double price, Date expirationDate) {
        super(id, description, price);
        this.expirationDate = expirationDate;
    }.. and so on
```

Is this a proper way of doing this? And second, how can I call my variable `DELIVERY` from `Food`?

Hope I'm clear in my question.

Comment: "Is this a proper way of doing this?" - do what? Inheritance? You did it. "how can I call my variable 'DELIVERY' from Food" - just use it. It is defined there, so no problem to refer it.

Comment: @AlexR: How can you access a child field from the parent?

Comment: Do I have to specify a variable in the parent class in one way or another for the delivery?

Comment: member variables cannot be overridden like methods. Anyway if you want to use a variable in both classes (parent and child) define it in the parent (as protected) otherwise define it inside the child class.

Answer (score 1):

> Every product has a deliverytime

I guess you want to be able to access this information from the outside, for any product. So your Product class must have a method like the following:

```
/**
 * Returns the delivery time for this product, in days
 */
public int getDeliveryTime()
```

Now you have to wonder. Is the delivery time a fixed value for every product, that can be computed at construction time and never changes afterwards, or is the delivery time computed from other fields of a product, or obeys to a formula. In the first case, the delivery time can be a field of the Product class, initialized in the constructor:

```
private int deliveryTime;

protected Product(int id, String description, double price, int deliveryTime) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.price = price;
    this.deliveryTime = deliveryTime;
}

/**
 * Returns the delivery time for this product, in days
 */
public int getDeliveryTime() {
    return deliveryTime;
}
```

In the second case, (which seems to be your case), you should let each subclass compute the delivery time as it wants to:

```
/**
 * Returns the delivery time for this product, in days
 */
public abstract int getDeliveryTime();
```

and in Food, for example:

```
@Override
public int getDeliveryTime() {
    return 1; // always 1 for Food. Simplest formula ever
}
```

The cool thing is that the users of the Product class and subclasses don't need to care how this is implemented. All they know is that each `Product` has a `getDeliveryTime()` method. The way it's implemented is irrelevant for them, and can be changed without changing anything in the caller code. That's the beauty of encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

If every product has a delivery time, then it'd better to put in the base class.

```
public abstract class Product {

private int id;
private String description;
private double price;

protected final int deliveryTime;

public Product(int id, String description, double price, int deliveryTime) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.price = price;
    this.deliveryTime = deliveryTime;
}
```

and

```
public class Food extends Product{
public Food(int id, String description, double price, Date expirationDate) {
    super(id, description, price, 1);
    this.expirationDate = expirationDate;
}
//...
}
```

I made DELIVERY protected in the mother class, but you might as well make it private and have a setter/getter (only if you want that field to be accessible from other parts of your code though).